# Econometrics- Multiple Regression

Tags: regression, economics

I have conducted a multiple regression analysis online, however, I'm having a hard time understanding the results. can someone please explain them to me.

Im actually doing a research paper which evaluates FTA's in increasing economic growth in South Korea. the results in the multiple regression analysis are based on data from 1995-2016. Since FTA's come under trade openness, I'm focusing on that in the analysis.

[image: Regression Results]

[image: Regression Results]

[image: Regression Results]

[image: Regression Results]

Answer (score 0):

There is not an exact rule, but you would normally want to keep any variable with an absolute value of the t-statistic >2. You have a few variables which are marginal so I would drop those that have a small absolute t-statistic then rerun the regression to see how that works out.
Some of these variables are not really independent, like Imports, Exports and Trade Balance. I wouldn't want to see all 3 in a model in any case so maybe drop Unemployment, Imports and Exports and rerun that.